# How to remove Input Form and paste URL directly on facebook V2.7 JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Sorry Idont know how to explain or type exact tittle on my question, anyway i will try to explain it here.

**What I need?**
I dont Required this
`<form id="get_shares">
  <input type="text" id="url" placeholder="Input URL" size="50" />
  <button>Get shares</button>
</form>` rather i need to just paste the `url` directly like this:
`#url=http://youtube.com`

My Question is how to implement this or how to do it? Thanks Guys

Here is the working code:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var token = "666987483466439|b3e1a0948513223b0bc51b32a735e2cf";
  $("#get_shares").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      type: "GET",
      data: { access_token: token, id: $("#url").val() },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#results").html(data.share.share_count);
        $("#comments").html(data.share.comment_count);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="get_shares">
  <input type="text" id="url" placeholder="Input URL" size="50" />
  <button>Get shares</button>
</form>


<span><strong>Shares:</strong></span>
<span id="results">0 Shares</span>
<div></div>

<span><strong>Comments:</strong></span>
<span id="comments">0 Comments</span>
```

Comment: Need  a more comprehensive explanation of your problem. What prevents you pasting into the input now?

Comment: i wanted to bypass my current php code...as facebook is keep on changing setup. to do that this is the easiest way

Comment: to get me- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47243037/how-to-get-facebook-share-count-and-comment-count-on-version-2-7 check this issued @charlietfl

Comment: That still doesn't explain what the actual problem is

Comment: Run the normal page with the parameters you want, and before hitting "get shares", open the network tab of your browser developer tools - you should be able to see the full GET url for the request in there.

Comment: I need to not to type... i wanted it to be automatic...

Comment: something like this `http://{$data.stat.domain}`

Comment: like this `<form id="get_shares">http://facebook.com</form>`

Comment: DO NOT MAKE ANY ACCESS TOKEN PUBLIC. invalidate your app secret in the app settings and don´t hardcode the app token in your client code. if you want to get shares, use server code instead to hide the app token. i really wonder why people keep posting tokens...it´s like giving everyone a key to your house. would you do that? i guess not.

Comment: also, if you really want to use the facebook api client side, use the js sdk instead of jquery ajax.

Comment: `id: $("#url").val()` -> `id: 'http://ifonlyiknewsomebasics.com/'` ...?

Comment: @luschin its a public token so i dont mind to let by anyone to used it... its like a public rest house in the field...thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issued!

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<div id="fb-like-div">0</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
var url = 'http://facebook.com';
var apiUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/?ids='+url;
$.ajax({url: apiUrl, success: function(result){

        $.each( result, function( key, val ) {

         console.log(key + ' - ' + val['share']['share_count']);

         var shareCount = val['share']['share_count'];
         
         $("#fb-like-div").html(shareCount);

    });

    }});

});
</script>
```